# When (not how or why) to calculate Big O of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I was asked this question in an interview recently and was curious as to what others thought.

"When should you calculate Big O?"

Most sites/books talk about HOW to calc Big O but not actually when you should do it. I'm an entry level developer and I have minimal experience so I'm not sure if I'm thinking on the right track. My thinking is you would have a target Big O to work towards, develop the algorithm then calculate the Big O. Then try to refactor the algorithm for efficiency.

My question then becomes is this what actually happens in industry or am I far off?

Comment: You should understand the performance of every single method you write.  If it takes a variable-sized input, and the complexity isn't obvious to you, then you should calculate it as part of this understanding.

Comment: I think *when* and *why* are closely linked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> "When should you calculate Big O?"

When you care about the *Time Complexity* of the algorithm.

When do I care?

When you need to make your algorithm to be able to *scale*, meaning that it's expected to have big datasets as input to your algorithm (e.g. number of points and number of dimensions in a nearest neighbor algorithm).

Most notably, when you want to *compare algorithms*!

You are asked to do a task, for which several algorithms can be applied to. Which one do you choose? You compare the Space, Time and development/maintenance complexities of them, and choose the one that best fits your needs.

Comment: Intersting. I didn't think about incorporating scalability into the answer. I'll make sure to consider that going forward. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome @BrianPhair, check my edit about using Time complexity as a powerful semaphore to compare algorithms. Good luck with your interview, good question.

Comment: Add cost, development time and maintenance time into the equation so people know that scaling up has costs; otherwise everyone thinks they are Google.

Comment: @Paddy3118 agreed, answer updated. I had used implementation, but development seems  nicer.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I upvoted but didn't realize about the accepting of answers. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Big O or asymptotic notations allow us to analyze an algorithm's running time by identifying its behavior as the input size for the algorithm increases.

So whenever you need to analyse your algorithm's behavior with respect to growth of the input, you will calculate this. Let me give you an example -

Suppose you need to query over 1 billion data. So you wrote a `linear search` algorithm. So is it okay? How would you know? You will calculate Big-o. It's O(n) for `linear search`. So in worst case it would execute 1 billion instruction to query. If your machine executes 10^7 instruction per second(let's assume), then it would take 100 seconds. So you see - you are getting an runtime analysis in terms of growth of the input.

Answer (score 0):

When we are solving an algorithmic problem we want to test the algorithm irrespective of hardware where we are running the algorithm. So we have certain asymptotic notation using which we can define the time and space complexities of our algorithm.

1. **Theta-Notation**: Used for defining average case complexity as it bounds the function from top and bottom
2. **Omega-Notation**: Bounds the function from below. It is used for best-time complexity
3. **Big-O Notation**: This is important as it tells about worst-case complexity and it bounds the function from top.

Now I think the answer to **Why BIG-O is calculated** is that using it we can get a fair idea that how bad our algorithm can perform as the size of input increases. And If we can optimize our algorithm for worst case then average and best case will take care for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to ask "when should I calculate time complexity?", just to avoid technicalities about Theta, Omega and Big-O.

Right attitude is to **guess** it almost always. Notable exceptions include piece of code you want to run just once and you are sure that it will never receive bigger input.

The emphasis on guess is because it does not matter that much whether complexity is constant or logarithmic. There is also a little difference between O(n^2) and O(n^2 log n) or between O(n^3) and O(n^4). But there is a big difference between constant and linear.

The main goal of the guess, is the answer to the question: "What happens if I get 10 times larger input?". If complexity is constant, nothing happens (in theory at least). If complexity is linear, you will get 10 times larger running time. If complexity is quadratic or bigger, you start to have problems.
Secondary goal of the guess is the answer to question: 'What is the biggest input I can handle?". Again quadratic will get you up to 10000 at most. O(2^n) ends around 25.

This might sound scary and time consuming, but in practice, getting time complexity of the code is rather trivial, since most of the things are either constant, logarithmic or linear.

Answer (score -1):

It represents the upper bound.
Big-oh is the most useful because represents the worst-case behavior. So, it guarantees that the program will terminate within a certain time period, it may stop earlier, but never later.

It gives the worst time complexity or maximum time require to execute the algorithm

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not correct. Big-O denotes an asymptotic upper bound, but it can be applied to any function, not just worst-case performance. In fact, it's not unusual to apply it to average/expected-case performance. (That said, it's true that people often use big-O to mean the big-Θ of the worst case.)